# How can I use buck to build react-native apps for both iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, buck

Buck sounds like a great tool for both iOS and Android projects but I have not been abel to find any information on how to use it for react-native projects.

**Update**

Looks like there is some work being done on this but it may not be recommended yet.

https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/31#issuecomment-164897170
https://github.com/facebook/buck/tree/master/test/com/facebook/buck/js

**Update 2**

Product Pains link https://productpains.com/post/react-native/add-buck-as-a-build-option

Comment: Could you narrow this down to a more specific problem? Right now I don't see how one could reliably answer this without writing a complete guide to setting up and building react-native projects with buck, which to me seems a bit too broad.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 8/6/2017:**

I tried following my steps below for integrating React Native into an iOS app with Buck but I ran into issues when using React Native 0.47. Instead I have a new simpler approach for getting React Native working with Buck on iOS by linking to prebuilt libraries. I forked the Buck sample project repo and have it working with React Native in [this repo](https://github.com/lyahdav/bucksamples). I also updated the [README](https://github.com/lyahdav/bucksamples/blob/master/cross-platform-scale-2015-demo/README.md#react-native-ios-only) in that repo with instructions for running the demo Buck React Native iOS app and how to integrate yourself.

Note there are a couple issues with this approach documented in the README that may or may not be a problem for using this in a production app.

That repo also doesn't bundle the JS for production yet.

---

**Older answer:**

I got Buck working with an iOS project. It is very much a work in progress, but works. A few notes:

- I manually copied files from `node_modules/react-native/React` and
  `node_modules/react-native/Libraries` (see folder structure below).
- I had to add the `-w` and `Wno-error` flags to each library because the main project had treat warnings as errors and I didn't want to see all of these React Native warnings in Xcode.
- You may have to add more libraries following the pattern. It also helps to look at the React Native [podspec](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React.podspec).
- There is probably opportunity to clean things up like there is no need for `reactnative.xcodeproj` in the `vendor/reactnative` folder (see below).
- There is probably some work needed to correctly bundle the JS for production. Currently it will only work if the JS is fetched from a server (e.g. Node.js).

Here is my `vendor/reactnative/BUCK` file:

```
apple_library(
  name = 'ReactNative',
  srcs = glob([
    'React/**/*.m',
    'React/**/*.mm',
    'React/**/*.c',
    'React/**/*.S',
  ]),
  exported_headers = glob([
    'React/**/*.h',
  ]),
  system_frameworks = [
    'JavaScriptCore'
  ],
  exported_linker_flags = [
    '-lc++',
  ],
  compiler_flags = [
    '-Wno-error',
    '-w'
  ],
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
)

apple_library(
  name = 'RCTWebSocket',
  srcs = glob([
    'Libraries/WebSocket/*.m',
  ]),
  headers = glob([
    'React/**/*.h',
  ]),
  exported_headers = glob([
    'Libraries/WebSocket/*.h',
  ]),
  compiler_flags = [
    '-Wno-error',
    '-w'
  ],
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
  deps = [
    ':ReactNative',
  ]
)

apple_library(
  name = 'RCTNetwork',
  srcs = glob([
    'Libraries/Network/*.m',
  ]),
  headers = glob([
    'React/**/*.h',
  ]),
  exported_headers = glob([
    'Libraries/Network/*.h',
  ]),
  compiler_flags = [
    '-Wno-error',
    '-w'
  ],
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
  deps = [
    ':ReactNative',
  ]
)

apple_library(
  name = 'RCTText',
  srcs = glob([
    'Libraries/Text/*.m',
  ]),
  headers = glob([
    'React/**/*.h',
  ]),
  exported_headers = glob([
    'Libraries/Text/*.h',
  ]),
  compiler_flags = [
    '-Wno-error',
    '-w'
  ],
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
  deps = [
    ':ReactNative',
  ]
)

apple_library(
  name = 'RCTImage',
  srcs = glob([
    'Libraries/Image/*.m',
  ]),
  headers = glob([
    'React/**/*.h',
    'Libraries/Network/*.h'
  ]),
  exported_headers = glob([
    'Libraries/Image/*.h',
  ]),
  compiler_flags = [
    '-Wno-error',
    '-w'
  ],
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
  deps = [
    ':ReactNative',
    ':RCTNetwork'
  ]
)
```

Here is the folder structure inside a vendor folder in my project:

```
vendor/reactnative
├── BUCK
├── Libraries
│   ├── ART
│   ├── ActionSheetIOS
│   ├── AdSupport
│   ├── Animated
│   ├── AppRegistry
│   ├── AppState
│   ├── BatchedBridge
│   ├── BugReporting
│   ├── CameraRoll
│   ├── Components
│   ├── CustomComponents
│   ├── DebugComponentHierarchy
│   ├── Devtools
│   ├── EventEmitter
│   ├── Experimental
│   ├── Fetch
│   ├── Geolocation
│   ├── Image
│   ├── Inspector
│   ├── Interaction
│   ├── JavaScriptAppEngine
│   ├── LayoutAnimation
│   ├── Linking
│   ├── LinkingIOS
│   ├── Modal
│   ├── NativeAnimation
│   ├── NavigationExperimental
│   ├── Network
│   ├── Promise.js
│   ├── PushNotificationIOS
│   ├── QuickPerformanceLogger
│   ├── RCTTest
│   ├── RKBackendNode
│   ├── ReactIOS
│   ├── ReactNative
│   ├── Sample
│   ├── Settings
│   ├── Storage
│   ├── StyleSheet
│   ├── Text
│   ├── Utilities
│   ├── Vibration
│   ├── WebSocket
│   ├── promiseRejectionIsError.js
│   ├── react-native
│   └── vendor
├── React
│   ├── Base
│   ├── Executors
│   ├── Layout
│   ├── Modules
│   ├── Profiler
│   └── Views
└── reactnative.xcodeproj
    ├── project.pbxproj
    └── xcuserdata
```

Then in the `deps` of my main BUCK file I add:

```
'//vendor/reactnative:ReactNative',
'//vendor/reactnative:RCTWebSocket',
'//vendor/reactnative:RCTText',
'//vendor/reactnative:RCTNetwork',
'//vendor/reactnative:RCTImage'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no official documentation / template for building RN apps with Buck yet but it shouldn't be that hard. You'd need to add a BUCK file that does the equivalent of what your [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/build.gradle) file does.

It's mostly just:

- Declares an Android app with a dependency on [React Native from JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.facebook.react%3Areact-native/view) (Buck has the [`android_binary`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/android_binary.html) rule to do that)
- In release mode it also [bundles the JS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/react.gradle) into your app's assets
  folder. You could skip this for a start (in dev mode the app fetches the JS from localhost at runtime) but I believe Buck has built-in support for bundling JS too.

Comment: link is broken for "bundles the JS"