# React native build with Buck and Nuclide features

Tags: ios, react-native, buck, nuclide-editor

I'm currently evaluating Nuclide Facebook Editor to write react-native projects. 
In order to benefit of all Nuclide's feature i have to build my rn project with Buck build tool. 
Unfortunately i wasn't able to find out a detailed explanation neither a sample project to make this happen.

I found here this one [How can I use buck to build react-native apps for both iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997158/how-can-i-use-buck-to-build-react-native-apps-for-both-ios-and-android), but i'm still missing something

**[Same question on github](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/682)**

Thank you!